# Late answers queue 'Other action' text uses 'question' instead of 'answer'

Tags: bug, status-review, review-queues, user-interface, late-answers

While reviewing Late **answers**, I noticed that the text under *Other action* reads *You have taken one or more actions on this **question** and have finished your review.*

Shouldn't this say **answer** instead of **question**?

[image]